# AngularJS - Default value when var is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying this:

```
$scope.items = {
    current: item.number || 1
};
```

And i'm getting:
`Error: item.number is undefined`

How to set the `current` to `1` when `item.number`is undefined?

Comment: I believe `number` should be `current` in the object. If so, use `$scope.items = {
    current: this.current || 1
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This errors because item itself is undefined.  Try:

```
current: item && item.number ? item.number : 1
```

If it's possible for item.number to be 0, change this to:

```
current: item && item.number !== undefined ? item.number : 1
```

0 is falsey so would be overwritten by 1 in the first case.

Comment: Some parens here would be nice, would make this easier to read

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.items = {
  current: (item && typeof item.number != "undefined") ? item.number : 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple if-else:

```
$scope.items = {}
if(item.number == undefined) {
    $scope.items.current = 1;
}
else {
    $scope.items.current = item.number;
}
```